# Forward Sweep of Matrices with Different Dimensions Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

i have a problem trying to replace (copy) values from a vector to a matrix. So given this matrix

```
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 1     1     1
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
 0     0     1
```

the plan is to copy values from this vector V=[0;10;20;30;40;50;60;70;80;90;100;110;120] starting from 10 ,V(2), into columns of the above matrix , to obtain this:

```
     10     40     70
     20     50     180
     30     60     190
     0      0      100
     0      0      110
     0      0      120
```

Help please ,thank you programmers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use that code:

```
a=[ 1 1 1;1 1 1;1 1 1;0 0 1;0 0 1;0 0 1];
V=[0;10;20;30;40;50;60;70;80;90;100;110;120];
a(a==1)=V(2:end)
```

The first two rows of code is to form the arrays in matlab.
The trird row of code set the non-zero values of the a array to be the values of V from the second element to the last.
In this way you can replace the vector as you like.

Comment: it does exactly what i wanted .Thanx you very much :)